# How to sync a loopback device when the underlying file is changed

Tags: linux, filesystems

The data being displayed on a mount of a loop device is incorrect when the data in the underlying file is changed.

Example:

```
$ mkdir drv
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=data.ext4 bs=1M count=10
$ mkfs.ext4 data.ext4
$ losetup /dev/loop0 data.ext4
$ mount /dev/loop0 drv
$ echo "abcdefg" > drv/test.txt
$ cat drv/test.txt
abcdefg
$ hexdump -C data.ext4 | grep abcd
00169000  61 62 63 64 65 66 67 0a  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |abcdefg.........|
$ sed -i 's/abcd/zzzz/g' data.ext4
$ hexdump -C data.ext4 | grep zzzz
00169000  7a 7a 7a 7a 65 66 67 0a  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |zzzzefg.........|
$ cat drv/test.txt 
abcdefg
$ hexdump -C data.ext4 | grep abcd
$
```

The string "abcd" is no longer in the backing data.ext4 file, yet when the test.txt file is cat, abcd is still seen.  How can I sync the loop to properly display what the backing file truly has?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Maybe try the `--direct-io=on` option.

Comment: --direct-io=on makes no difference in the above test.  I don't think what I want can be accomplished, but I'll post on the other forums you suggest.